# black box around drawRect shape swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, drawrect

I'm trying to learn Core Graphics and I have having this problem when using drawRect. (picture below)

I made a class that inherits from UIView which has the drawRect code. From my viewcontroller class, I than set the dimensions and add the subview.

The result is getting the image with a black box around my shape. How can I fix this?

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

var bg = Background()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bg = Background(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50))
    self.view.addSubview(bg)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(bg)
}


class Background: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
    path.fill()

  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the background color of your `bg` element, just add this row `bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`. So in your viewDidLoad method, update the code to:

```
bg = Background(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50))
bg.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.view.addSubview(bg)
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(bg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the rect

```
class Background: UIView {
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
    path.fill()
  }
}
```